# Using regular expressions to find img tags without an alt attribute

Tags: regex, visual-studio, find, accessibility, standards

I am going through a large website (1600+ pages) to make it pass Priority 1 W3C WAI.  As a result, things like image tags need to have alt attributes.

What would be the regular expression for finding img tags without alt attributes?  If possible, with a wee explanation so I can use to find other issues.

I am in an office with Visual Web Developer 2008.  The Edit >> Find dialogue can use regular expressions.

Comment: If the goal is to find images without alt tags (as opposed to the constraint of finding them only via using regex), a viable option is to use Screaming Frog SEO. The free version of this software can crawl your site to see all the alt text (and missing alt tags) for every image on your site, as well as to locate all broken links, redirected urls, and dozens of other auditing tasks. Highly recommended for checking all types of errors and best practices for your website. Good for checking your site, even after your regex fix. https://www.screamingfrog.co.uk/how-to-find-missing-image-alt-text/

Comment: Note: the free version has a limit of 500urls per crawl, but using a robots file and adjusting some settings, I think you can work around that to run 4 separate crawls to cover all the urls. This tutorial]of theirs lists ways to limit the crawl for large sites (specifically, look at numbers 4-6): https://www.screamingfrog.co.uk/how-to-crawl-large-websites/  The paid version, in addition to unlimited urls per crawl, has so many additional useful features for fine tuning websites, that if you have it, their 99£ price for the pro version is money/time well spent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is really tricky, because regular expressions are mostly about matching something that is there. With look-around trickery, you can do things like 'find A that is not preceded/followed by B', etc. But I think the most pragmatic solution for you wouldn't be that.

My proposal relies a little bit on your existing code not doing too crazy things, and you might have to fine-tune it, but I think it's a good shot, if you really want to use a RegEx-search for your problem.

So what I suggest would be to find all img tags, that *can* (but don't need to) have all valid attributes for an img-element. Whether that is an approach you can work with is for you to decide.

Proposal:

```
/<img\s*((src|align|border|height|hspace|ismap|longdesc|usemap|vspace|width|class|dir|lang|style|title|id)="[^"]"\s*)*\s*\/?>/
```

The current limitations are:

1. It expects your attribute values to be delimited by double quotes,
2. It doesn't take into account possible inline on*Event attributes,
3. It doesn't find img elements with 'illegal' attributes.

Comment: It didn't work straight off, but it's a good enough shot to vote up: I have learnt things from your answer, for example, the need to finally get to grips with regex.  I also think that VS's Find could allow iterative searches.  Combined with a facility for putting a string that ISN'T there (eg, alt=") would make this a doddle.  Oh, well.

Comment: @awrigley: Have you been able to pinpoint what's not working? For example, I've included the `/`slashes as RegEx delimiters. That might not be necessary at all. Including all (legal) events isn't hard at all, I just didn't want to do the typing. As long as your current image tags are at least trying to be valid, this should be extendable to a useful search expression.

Comment: I have tried without the delimiters as well, but no joy.  I think I have located most of them manually, but even introducing a fault, the results returned are 0.  Can't blame you for not wanting to type.

Comment: up against the deadline now, will just have to research this later.

Comment: @awrigley: Sure, if you've gone through manually there's no point in spending too much time on this. When you have a minute or two, it'd be lovely if you could post a couple of samples that it should find (but doesn't, currently). I've actually tested it against a few cases I made up, and it seemed to perform nicely, so I'm hopeful that it could be fixed to work for you. However, no pressure. If you have to get your work done, do that. For me, it's all but academical interest. ;)

Comment: There is a `*` missing in the attribute value part, it should be `<img\s*((src|align|border|height|hspace|ismap|longdesc|usemap|vspace|width|class|dir|lang|style|title|id)="[^"]*"\s*)*\s*\/?>`

Answer (score 47):

Building on Mr.Black and Roberts126 answers:

```
/(<img(?!.*?alt=(['"]).*?\2)[^>]*)(>)/
```

This will match an img tag anywhere in the code which either has no alt tag or an alt tag which is not followed by ="" or ='' (i.e. invalid alt tags).

Breaking it down:

```
(          : open capturing group
<img       : match the opening of an img tag
(?!        : open negative look-ahead
.*?        : lazy some or none to match any character
alt=(['"]) : match an 'alt' attribute followed by ' or " (and remember which for later)
.*?        : lazy some or none to match the value of the 'alt' attribute
\2)        : back-reference to the ' or " matched earlier
[^>]*      : match anything following the alt tag up to the closing '>' of the img tag
)          : close capturing group
(>)        : match the closing '>' of the img tag
```

If your code editor allows search and replace by Regex you can use this in combination with the replace string:

```
$1 alt=""$3
```

To find any alt-less img tags and append them with an empty alt tag.  This is useful when using spacers or other layout images for HTML emails and the like.

Comment: I modified this to become `/(<img(?!.*?alt=(['"]).*?\2)[^>]*?)(/?>)/` which means you can use `\1\2 alt=''\3` as your replacement text, and any self-closing tag slashes will stay on the end.

Comment: how do I update the regex so it will update alt attribute with img src filename? From: `<img src="my/w3schools.jpg" alt="" width="104" height="142">
<img src="my/w3schools.jpg" width="104" height="142">` To: `<img src="my/w3schools.jpg" alt="w3schools" width="104" height="142">
<img src="my/w3schools.jpg" width="104" height="142" alt="w3schools">`

Answer (score 25):

Here is what I just tried in my own environment with a massive enterprise code base with some good success (found no false positives but definitely found valid cases):

```
<img(?![^>]*\balt=)[^>]*?>
```

What's going on in this search:

1. find the opening of the tag
2. look for the absence of zero or more characters that are not the closing bracket while also …
3. Checking for the absence of of a word that begins with "alt" ("\b" is there for making sure we don't get a mid-word name match on something like a class value) and is followed by "=", then …
4. look for zero or more characters that are not the closing bracket
5. find the closing bracket

So this will match:

```
<img src="foo.jpg" class="baltic" />
```

But it won't match either of these:

```
<img src="foo.jpg" class="baltic" alt="" />
<img src="foo.jpg" alt="I have a value.">
```

Comment: I found this extremely useful for doing RegEx Find/Replace in Visual Studio. None of the other suggestions worked properly, likely due to the need to escape some characters. It did find a couple false positives, but only because the img tag contained an ASP markup inside of it: `<img src="<%=Resources.Images.ImageName%> alt="<%=Resources.Text.Cancel%>" />`

Comment: This was really helpful to find ADA issues in my company's code.

Answer (score 10):

This works in Eclipse:

`<img(?!.*alt).*?>`

I'm updating for Section 508 too!

Comment: A great site for testing your regular expressions is http://regexpal.com/.  I use that and http://www.regular-expressions.info/ to build mine BUT its never easy.

Comment: That works, Mr.Black, provided your img tag is not broken across multiple lines (very possible with template systems) because the ".*" will stop matching across line breaks. It's safer to look for _any_ character that's not the closing bracket there. Also, you'll want to made sure you're not matching "class='baltic'" and then skipping over a true positive by checking for a word break before "alt". I've provided an example with detailed explanation in another comment, but here's what I found works: "<img(?![^>]*\balt=)[^>]*?>"

Comment: This worked for me in Visual Studio and in Sublime Text.

Answer (score 7):

This worked for me.

```
^<img(?!.*alt).*$
```

This matches any string beginning with `<img` that doesn't contain any number of characters before an alt attribute.  It even works for `src="<?php echo $imagename; ?>"` type of attributes.

Answer (score 3):

This is perfectly possible with following regEx:

```
<img([^a]|a[^l]|al[^t]|alt[^=])*?/?>
```

Looking for something that isn't there, is rather tricky, but we can trick them back, by looking for a group that doesn't start with 'a', or an 'a' that doesn't get followed by an 'l' and so on.

Comment: Perfect solution! 

Comment: Missed on few images, such as: <img class="negocios" src="assets/images/vender/negocios.png">

Removing ?/ from the end fixed it!

Comment: Yes, this is of course the solution IF your img-tags are self-closing. At the moment the correct way of writing img-tags is non-self-closing, so I will edit the solution as such.

Answer (score 0):

Simple and effective:

`<img((?!\salt=).)*?`

This regex works for find `<img>` tags missing the `alt` attribute.

Comment: This only works if you also close out your regex with a closing html-tag '>'. Otherwise it will trigger on all images. So it becomes ```<img((?!\salt=).)*?>```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a simple code for this without Regex

```
let arr = []
$('img')
.filter(function() {
  arr.push(this.alt)
})
document.write(arr.filter(a=>!a).length + ' img without alt tag')
```

Answer (score -1):

`<img(?!(\n|.(?!\/>))*?alt)`

```
<img - Find start of image tag
(?! - begin negative lookahead
( - begin group
\n|.(?!\/>) - Match either a new line or anything not followed by end of the tag
)*? - close group. Match zero or more (non-greedy)
alt - Match "alt" literally
) end of negative lookahead
```

This one works for me in vscode. It will highlight the beginning of all the img tags without an alt attribute