# Finding image tags outside markdown code blocks

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, bash, markdown

### Intro

I have a couple of hundred markdown files with code blocks in them, and they look something like this.

````
```html
<img src="fil.png">
```

- [ ] Here is another image <img src="fil.png"> and another `<img src="fil.png">`

  ```html
  <a href="scratch/index.html" id="scratch" data-original-title="" title="" aria-describedby="popover162945">
    <div class="logo-wrapper">
    </div>
    <div class="name">
      <span>Scratch</span>
    </div>
    <img src="fil.png">
  </a>
  ```
````

***My goal is to find all IMG tags* without *an alt tag,* outside *the code blocks.***

Not sure if I can use an HTML: parser either,, because of the codeblocks...

### Examples

I am not looking for the perfect solution, just something that will find simple img tags spanning multiple lines.

````
```html
<img src="fil.png">
```
````

Should not find this one, as it is inside an img block.

```
- [ ] Here is another image `<img src="fil.png">` and another <img src="dog.png" title: "re
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaallllyl long title">
```

Should not find the first one (as it is surrounded by `), however it should find the second one even if it spans multiple lines.

### Attempt

I have tried a couple of different methods, using everything from bash and grep to python. I can obtain the `img` tags using the following regex

```
<img(\s*(?!alt)([\w\-])+=([\"\'])[^\"\']+\3)*\s*\/?>
```

However I feel a cleaner approach might be this

1. Filter out every code block
2. find every img tag
3. find every img tag without an alt tag

I am a little stuck on the first step. I can find every code block using this regex:

````
```[a-z]*\n[\s\S]*?\n```
````

However I am not sure how to invert that, e.g find all text outside it. I would accept any solutions that can be run in a bash script, or from python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are absolutely right, this is a classic case for the regex trashcan approach: We *SKIP what's to avoid in the overall match and use a capturing group for what we actually want, i.e. `What_I_want_to_avoid|(What_I_want_to_match)`:

````
```.*?```|`.*?`|(<img(?!.*?alt=(['\"]).*?\2)[^>]*)(>)
````

The idea here is to completely disregard the overall matches returned by the regex engine: that's the trash bin. Instead, we only need to check capture group $1, which, when set, contains the img-tags.

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/P0nSQG/2/)

The pattern to match img-tags without an alt attribute is [borrowed here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17784634/8291949).
The trashcan approach is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24535912/8291949) and [here](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html).

[Sample Code](https://ideone.com/1X9M5e):

````
import re
regex = r"```.*?```|`.*?`|(<img(?!.*?alt=(['\"]).*?\2)[^>]*)(>)"
test_str = ("```html\n"
    "<img src=\"fil.png\">\n"
    "```\n\n"
    "- [ ] Here is another image <img src=\"fil.png\"> and another `<img src=\"fil.png\">`\n\n"
    "  ```html\n"
    "  <a href=\"scratch/index.html\" id=\"scratch\" data-original-title=\"\" title=\"\" aria-describedby=\"popover162945\">\n"
    "    <div class=\"logo-wrapper\">\n"
    "    </div>\n"
    "    <div class=\"name\">\n"
    "      <span>Scratch</span>\n"
    "    </div>\n"
    "    <img src=\"fil.png\">\n"
    "  </a>\n"
    "  ```")

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.DOTALL)
for match in matches:
    if match.group(1):
        print ("Found at {start}-{end}: {group}".format(start = match.start(1), end = match.end(1), group = match.group(1)))
````

Actually, it would be sufficient to just put a [single backtick pair](https://regex101.com/r/P0nSQG/3) in the full match. However, it is arguably more readable and demonstrates the idea clearer as shown above.

Comment: @ØisteinSøvik As a quick follow-up, here is an optimized version of the pattern using a negated character group and possessive quantifiers group: [``+[^`]++`+|...`](https://regex101.com/r/P0nSQG/4) to make use of it requires to use the alternative [regex](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) package for python: import regex as re

Answer (score 0):

My approach is to remove all strings between `` "`" ``, and then just supply the text to BeautifulSoup for parsing (i will find all `img` tags without `alt` attribute and print it's `src`):

````
data = """
```html
<img src="fil.png">
```

- [ ] Here is another image <img src="fil.png"> and another `<img src="fil.png">`

  ```html
  <a href="scratch/index.html" id="scratch" data-original-title="" title="" aria-describedby="popover162945">
    <div class="logo-wrapper">
    </div>
    <div class="name">
      <span>Scratch</span>
    </div>
    <img src="fil.png">
  </a>
  ```
  """

import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(re.sub(r'`+[^`]+`+', '', data), 'lxml')
for img in soup.find_all(lambda t: t.name == 'img' and not 'alt' in t.attrs):
    print(img['src'])
````

Output:

```
fil.png
```